# get data correctly from table that only contains relations in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm doing practices with sequencing and I found a problem that I don't know, or rather I can't understand how to solve it, I have a table that I want to use just to relate 2 other table.

```
const TagRelations = Sequelize.define(
  "tag_relations",
  {
    entry_id: {
      type: sequelize.INTEGER,
      references: { model: "entries", key: "id" },
      allowNull: false
    },
    tag_id: {
      type: sequelize.INTEGER,
      references: { model: "tag", key: "id" },
      allowNull: false
    }
  },
  {
    // options
    underscored: true
  }
Entries.hasMany(TagRelations);
Tag.belongsToMany(Entries, { through: TagRelations });
```

This is how you can see an api practice of a simple blog, I know that the associations use them internally in sequelize when calling it in the controller to be able to do:

```
   include:[{
    model: Category,
    required: true
     }]
```

and I the data of the category related to an entry, but I don't understand how to call the related tags in this way, I have a block with this topic, so if someone with more experience could explain to me how to handle this detail or indicate if it necessary, structure it in another way, we would appreciate it.

Comment: What is your goal? To select entries along with their tags?

Comment: I want the tags to be independent and can be associated with entries, I want to avoid placing a direct relationship to the entry in the tags entity, that is, I want the tags to be created separately, Associate them with a category as an option, and have tags_relations handle which tags are associated with an entry @Anatoly

Comment: Taking your association definitions into account you can do Tag.findAll({ include: [Entries] }) and Entries.findAll({ include: [TagRelations]} )